# I want disable automatically delete JMS queue in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

Auto deletion of queues should be turned off,

1)If set  "ems_value=true" in application.property file

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ems_value")
public class JmsConfiguration {  
 // Here get JMS connection
```

In this case what are mentioned queue names in application property file Its created by spring.

2)If set  "ems_value=false" in application.property file 
Queues deleted by spring class.

How can i disable or stop to delete queues.

Answer (score 0):

It will only work on startup anyway, but you can always use 2 different beans that will do required job for you. Have once component with

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ems_value", havingValue="true")
```

that will do whatever you require, and have another component  with

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ems_value", havingValue="false")
```

that will do cleanup operations only.